# How to launch already installed iOS App on iPhone remotely?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, remote-access, launch

I am currently working on an In-House Enterprise application for which I need to launch an already installed iOS app remotely, not considering jail broken devices & it should happen without user interaction.

Comment: you can launch another app from your application.if user has installed yours then probably using push notification you can able launch specific app from users device.

Comment: @DSDharma I don't want any user interaction as mentioned in question description. Let me know anything rather than this.

Comment: You can define a custom URL scheme (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html), but the user will have to click a link. It is not possible with no user interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry this can't be happen without user interaction. I am pretty sure about this.